# Counting excel cells within a time window

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a formula that will help count cells that fall within a time window. I came up with a formula but it only works when the time is from AM to PM and not for PM (previous day) to AM (next day). As shown in the image, I want to be able to count the number of Korea trades (from Table 2) within trading window (Table 3). I was trying to use the highlighted formula but apparently it's not working on Table 1.
Formula: =COUNTIFS(D13:D16, "*Korea*", E13:E16, ">="&H4, E13:E16, "<="&I4)
[image]Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: One thing you might be able to do is identify when Ending < Opening (indicating that it's an overnight trading window) and specifically search for those with a reversed formula

Comment: Just a question: you use "Korea" as a criterion of your `=IFS()` formula. Does this mean `equals "Korea"` or `contains "Korea"` and does this correspond with what you want?

Answer (score 0):

When the times cross midnight for Korea, you'll need to do an `OR` condition rather than an `and` condition. You could do this by making two countifs functions or use Sumproduct as shown below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D13:D16="Korea")*((E13:E16>=H3)+(E13:E16<=I3)))
```

Comment: This works but it only considers cases where Korea is the only listed country. Any idea on how we can make the formula consider all trades where Korea is listed and falls within the time window (like trade ID 01003X)

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't your question. I'd be most grateful if you marked this as `accepted` since it appears to have addressed your stated issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a version of Excel that supports the [Lambda](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function I’d suggest creating a lambda that does the *within* checking so it’s not done through the formulas on your sheet. Unfortunately I don’t think there are Ifs functions that take a lamdba as a criteria but you might be able to use Map to generate an array of booleans and get the product similar to the other reply.

So I started by creating a lambda for determining if the value is in the range. The formula I used is:

```
=LAMBDA(s,e,IF(s<e,LAMBDA(x,AND(x>=s,x<e)),LAMBDA(x,OR(x<e,x>s))))
```

That basically takes 2 parameters - your starting time and the ending time for the range. It will return a lambda that will take the time to compare. And I added that as a namedreference named “IsWithin” [image: IsWithin lambda]

Then I created another lambda that would do the overall count.

```
=LAMBDA(rangeMatch,textMatch,rangeTime,start,end,SUM(MAP(rangeMatch,LAMBDA(x,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(textMatch,x))))*MAP(rangeTime,IsWithin(start,end))))
```

The function takes 5 parameters:

1. the range for which you are searching for the country name
2. the text to match within the range
3. the range containing the times to evaluate
4. the start time for the valid range (e.g. H3)
5. the end time for the valid range (e.g. I3)

It uses the [Map](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function to evaluate the items in the range using lambdas. The first part of the evaluate creates an array of the items that have the matching text so either TRUE or FALSE. The second part creates an array of items that are within the specified time range - again either TRUE or FALSE. And then it just multiplies those arrays and sums the values essentially getting those where both values are true. Then to use it you just call that named reference:

```
=CountMatch(D13:D16,"Korea",E13:E16,H4,I4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(D13:D16)<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D13:D16,"Korea","")))*((E13:E16>=H4)+(E13:E16<=I4)))
```